# jQuery if list item contains ''-" .remove()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am restyling a list of related articles in a li and I would like to remove the "-" between the a tag and span without messing with the original content on the page (links). I must use jQuery and I'm not sure if there is a simple way of doing this.

```
<div class="related-articles card">
<h3 class="h2">
    <i class="fa fa-book text-brand-primary-dark"></i> Related Articles
</h3>

<ul>

<li>
    <a href="http://example.com/article-1">Title One</a>
            - 
    <span> Some Related Preview Text... </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://example.com/article-2">Title Two</a>
            - 
    <span> Some Related Preview Text... </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://example.com/article-3">Title Three</a>
            - 
    <span> Some  RelatedPreview Text... </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is:

```
$('.related-articles li a').map(function() {
    return this.nextSibling;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, get the children elements and assign it back, so the plain text present (`-`) will get removed!

```js
$('.related-articles li').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).children());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="related-articles card">
  <h3 class="h2">
    <i class="fa fa-book text-brand-primary-dark"></i> Related Articles
  </h3>

  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com/article-1">Title One</a> -
      <span> Some Related Preview Text... </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com/article-2">Title Two</a> -
      <span> Some Related Preview Text... </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.com/article-3">Title Three</a> -
      <span> Some  RelatedPreview Text... </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to loop through each `<li>`, extract the `<a>` and `<span>` elements and stitch them together manually, like this:

```js
$("ul > li").each( (i, li) => {
    const $li = $(li);
    const $a = $li.find("a");
    const $span = $li.find("span");
    
    //create a temp element with just the <a> and <span>
    const $tempItem = $("<li></li>");    
    $tempItem.append( $a ).append( $span );
    //copy new HTML into old element
    $li.html( $tempItem.html () );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>

<li>
    <a href="http://example.com/article-1">Title One</a>
            - 
    <span> Some Related Preview Text... </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://example.com/article-2">Title Two</a>
            - 
    <span> Some Related Preview Text... </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://example.com/article-3">Title Three</a>
            - 
    <span> Some  RelatedPreview Text... </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Naren's answer is better though!